# What is "link beat"?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a Linux 2.6 box that uses ifplugd to bring up the network. While initialising, the logs say, `"Initialisation complete. Link beat not detected."` and then it goes into releasing the present address and obtaining lease all over again.

My question therefore would be:

- What is link beat?
- What does it mean if a link beat is not detected?
- Why is this so critical? What determines if a link beat is present or not?

Answer (score 6):

**Link beat** is a signal generated by ports on ethernet hubs and switches; it allows your network card to detect/negotiate the speed of the connection and to verify that the connection is healthy.  If the card cannot detect the beat, it assumes the connection is faulty and retries.

- Test your cable to see if it is functioning (or try a new cable).
- Try connecting a different box to the same switch using the same cable.

This may help you identify the point of failure.

Comment: Still unclear about what causes "link beat"... Is thus some kind of crystal/oscillator in the network equipment? How is the beat detected? Is link beat a signalling protocol?